# Process in updating my app in the market

Tags: android, version, google-play

i have released a version 1 on some app in the market. Can anyone tell me how to give an update of it?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Increase the value of the `android:versionCode` attribute of the `<manifest>` element in your AndroidManifest.xml
- Build, sign, zipalign the apk as you did originally
- Go to http://market.android.com/publish/Home
- Click on the app name
- Click on `[Upload Upgrade]`
- Select the app and upload as you did originally

Comment: @Smith pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453965/how-to-update-the-android-app-in-android-market

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

check out the publishing update section in the above web page

Answer (score 0):

Just make an upgrade apk with the android:versionCode attribute incremented, and then publish through your developer console in the market.