# how to update the android app in android market

Tags: android, google-play

I saw many question addressing this issue but still i have some doubts...

I followed the steps given by **Chris Smith** in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468449/process-in-updating-my-app-in-the-market)

- Increase the value of the `android:versionCode` attribute of the `<manifest>` element in  your AndroidManifest.xml
- Build, sign, zipalign the apk as you did originally
- Go to http://market.android.com/publish/Home
- Click on the app name
- Click on `[Upload Upgrade]`

But no where  i could found **[Upload Upgrade]** option in developer console as he told.
Please see the image below [image]

Anyone knows what was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google changed the upgrade GUI so the post that you are referring to is no longer valid. 
From your screen

- click 'save' button
- click 'switch to advance mode' it will show multiple version of your APKs
- you will be able to 'activate' the desired version.

Comment: do you know what is replace and remove option?

Comment: Ex. given that you already uploaded v1.1. you may want to delete this version or update this version to use another APK file. (It is not adding the new version)

Comment: Okay thanks for your speedy reply still i have one doubt if i do like u told " it will show multiple version of your APK and you will be able to 'activate' the desired version." will i get the download statics from old version?

Comment: To see stats, go to https://market.android.com/publish/Home you will see the 'Statistics' link at the 3rd column. Unfortunately, it's a summary of all versions.